# Exception 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

i have drop down list and based on that i am populating another drop down list.I did with the help of JSON and jquery.But the problem is i was getting exception `0x800a1391 - JavaScript run time error: 'JSON' is undefined` .I solved it by running compatibility mode and un checking required on in Tools->compatibility.But now the biggest problem i am facing is my website alignment is badly affected.Do we have any alternative solution.Do we have any aternative approach than JSON?

Comment: Can you find the code that is trying to use the `JSON` object - is it for encoding or decoding? Is this in an old browser that wouldn't have it as a built-in? You can use jQuery's built-in encoder / decoder, or optionally include e.g. Crockford's one when the client doesn't have a built-in.

Comment: @Rup encoding decoding means, actually when first drop downlist select an item i am passing it in to the controller ,then controller will required items for second dropwonlist as Jason

Comment: Thanks, yes. Can we see the code that's giving you this error please?

Comment: @Rup i did it based on this link http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b58fde6b-415e-454d-985b-d5dc4ad2fca8.aspx

Comment: But website is big and it is painful to see that alignment go affected badly

Comment: OK, that means that your browser is missing `JSON.stringify` in the mode that renders fine. One solution is to include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) as a script on your page which will add it. You can use IE's conditional comments to only include this on IE6 or IE7 which is where I think you need it. But that must mean you're using IE7 or IE7 compatability mode? Does your site work well on other browsers e.g. Chrome or Firefox? I don't think there's any easy fix to get your CSS working in newer browsers - you'll just have to tackle each problem in turn.

Answer (score 0):

AS per Rup including jason2.js will fix the issue